# Creating a story map slideshow in Leaflet js from geoJSON file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I already asked this question on the gis stack exchange forum, but with no luck. I am reposting here in the hope that I may find an answer!

I am trying to create an interactive Leaflet map of a hiking trail. Along this trail, I have a number of 'waypoints', represented as markers in a GeoJSON file:

```
 var waypoints = [{ 
    "Name": "Cabane de Susanfe", 
    "Altitude": 2095, 
    "Text": "This is the first waypoint",
    "coordinates": [ 6.91246, 46.14939 ] 
    }, { 
    "Name": "Rhône Valley", 
    "Altitude": 457, 
    "Text": "This is the second waypoint",
    "coordinates": [ 7.0458, 46.13417 ]
    }, { 
    "Name": "Cabane de Sorniot", 
    "Altitude": 2064, 
    "Text": "This is the third waypoint",
    "coordinates": [ 7.09167, 46.16176 ] 
    }, {
    "Name": "Cabane du Demècre", 
    "Altitude": 2361, 
    "Text": "This is the fourth waypoint",
    "coordinates": [ 7.07314, 46.18744 ] 
    },
    ]
```

I would like to create a button in a separate div which would cycle through these waypoints and display information about each in a div on the side, like a map slideshow. So far I have managed to create a button that cycles through the elements in the 'waypoints' array, but how do I get the map to pan to the new marker and display information? Here is the jquery code I have so far to iterate through the array elements:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var i = 0;

      $("#button-next").on('click', function(){
         i = (i + 1) % waypoints.length;

         console.log(waypoints[i]);
    });
    });
```

The effect I am looking for is similar to CartoDB's odyssey.js slideshow or the jQuery slidemapper plugin, but I figure that there is probably an easier solution than completely rebuilding the map using one of these libraries.

I am a beginner with leaflet and javascript in general.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If I understand correctly, you would like an answer that explains how to rebuild the features of the libraries you mention, so that you can avoid adapting your code to the latter? Sounds like you expect unreasonable work for free, while you already have access to free libraries and their source code.

Comment: Fair enough. I was simply wondering if there was something obvious that I was missing. It seems like quite a simple problem, but if the easiest solution is really to use one of the libraries mentioned, I will just do that.

Comment: you'd add a `L.marker([lat, lon], {options})` with `.addTo(map)` and then center on it with `map.setView([lat, lon], zoom)`. there's [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147052/leaflet-js-map-pan-too-and-zoom-in-on-point) on GIS.SE, as one of many, even with the keyword 'story' in the title. BTW the docs on leaflet, and the map object in particular, are quite good...